# two events triggering with autocomplete after blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

So I'm working with autocomplete today and usually I don't have a problem, but today I'm getting an odd occurrence when either I chose the item from the list or   just use the typed in value. If I select the item from the list the event fires once, if I type the item in then tab to the next field it seems to trigger both a select and a change event. I only want the event to fire once regardless of what action I am doing.

I guess the other question I would have regarding this would be is, why is this occurring as well?

I have placed my code below. If there are any questions please ask!

**code**

```
$('#ee_id').autocomplete({
    delay : 0,
    source : "<?=APP_BASE?>/assets/server/autocomplete/geteeid.php",
    select : function(event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        koolajax.callback(getEmployeeInformation(ui.item.value), getEmployeeInformationDone);   
    },
    change : function(event, ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).val();
        koolajax.callback(getEmployeeInformation(value), getEmployeeInformationDone);   
    }
});

function getEmployeeInformationDone(response){
    if(response.status){
        $('#comcheckRequestForm').find('input, select, textarea').not($('#ee_id, #temp_agency, #purpose_code__id, #sender, #date')).prop('disabled', false);
        $('#first_name').val(response.first_name);
        $('#last_name').val(response.last_name);
        $('#temp_agency').prop('disabled', true);
    }else{
        bootbox.alert({
            message : response.error,
            backdrop : false,
            callback : function(){
                $('#comcheckRequestForm').find('input, select, textarea').not($('#ee_id, #temp_agency, #purpose_code__id, #sender, #date')).prop('disabled', true);
                $('#first_name').val('');
                $('#last_name').val('');
                $('#ee_id').focus();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing init for select event.

Comment: @pratikwebdev i did actually try that earlier, but it also failed

Comment: could you share JSFiddle?

Comment: a fiddle will not work with the above code that I have because it uses an extension not publicly available

Comment: Interesting. I would try removing preventDefault on events and see if default behavior addresses issue or not. Change event is called on closure of autocomplete and even if you are preventing event on select it will still get closed.